Angular 18 Installing json-server have this error File db.json not found
I am doing an Dummy Angular 18 Application. I am using Visual Code, and Node version v20.18.0
I am trying to install Json Server, so first I run the command npm install json-server
In package.json have the line  "json-server": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
But when I want to install the json.db running the command
json-server --watch db.json
or
npx json-server --watch db.json

I got this error
--watch/-w can be omitted, JSON Server 1+ watches for file changes by default
File db.json not found


What is your directory structure? Is db.json present in the same directory?

NO, I thought it was generated with the command. But I sow a blog that is generated by hand.... I did that.. but I dont know if it is correct. I never worked with json database before. For what you are saying, I have to create it by hand...
Thanks

No it doesn't generate any json files. It simply creates a http server and serves the file (that you ask it to do).
